# Нужен хостинг для изображения

Tags: rest, firebase, dart

В настоящее время я работаю над мобильным приложением (Flutter), в котором вы можете выбрать изображение, а затем получить его описание, используя Google Reverse Image API от SerpApi. (rest api)

Теперь я пытаюсь найти хостинг или хранилище, чтобы получить url изображения, и я использовалa Firebase Storage. Однако API не определил url адрес. Хотя я сделала всё публичным, так что я могу получить его без токена.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Дополнительно предоставлен открытый доступ в [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Сам google обратное изображение не может найти его, говоря о "Неверный URL или доступ к изображению ограничен". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]НО! Яндекс, с другой стороны, нашел его мгновенно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Проблема в том, что у Яндекса нет reverse image API... Не так ли?

Что мне теперь делать? Localhost? Другие хранилища или хостинг? Как-то использовать Яндекс без API?

Comment: на русский перевелите, пожалуйста. Или - на английскую часть SO. Но там могут быть не очень рады в наши дни картинкам с русским текстом...

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решён, если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой --> imgbb ваше спасение